# How to set up modern front-end development workflow with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio, vuejs2

How to set up Vue with ASP.NET Core using modern front-end development workflow? I'd like to use ES6, WebPack, Babel, Vue and still benefit from the features that ASP.NET Core has to offer.

Comment: While self answering questions is a valid practice....the questions themselves need to be on topic first. This question is not

Comment: I'd like to correct it. Could you give me a hint how to make it more on topic? These are my first steps as an author on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Perhaps this might be a better fit in [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation). As a question it is far too broad per [Don't ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and already has several close votes as a result

Comment: I'm relying on your experience here charlietfl. Feel free to move it wherever it fits best :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been coming across these questions more and more often. It is certainly possible for .NET developers to use JavaScript frameworks like React, Angular 2 or Vue and utilize modern front-end development workflow in the process.

The complete step by step guide is available in [this blog post.](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/aspnet-core-visual-studio-2017-vue-es6-es2015-dawid-dworak?trk=prof-post)

In short I could finally achieve it using the following **prerequisites**:

1. [Visual Studio 2017 RC](http://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_Professional.exe)
2. [Node JS](http://nodejs.org/dist/v6.9.5/node-v6.9.5-x64.msi)
3. [WebPack Task Runner](http://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebPackTaskRunner)
4. [Open Command Line for Visual Studio](http://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.OpenCommandLine)

Let me use the **Vue** framework to be specific but the following list of steps can be easily adapted to React or Angular.

1. Create new ASP.NET Core project (.NET Core) with basic set up in Visual Studio 2017
2. Install vue-cli using the Command Line and npm (package manager)

   ```
   npm install -g vue-cli
   ```
3. Create new Vue project with vue-cli in the Command Line in the context of Website folder

   ```
   vue init webpack-simple
   ```
4. Install the npm front-end packages

   ```
   npm install
   ```
5. Move the src folder under wwwroot/js and update the entry and output path fields in webpack.config.js
6. Write your code. The basic Hello World application using Vue would be:

   HTML:

   ```
   <div id="app" class="row">
     <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
   </div>
   ```

   JavaScript:

   ```
   import Vue from 'vue';

   new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     data: {
       title: 'Hello World!'
     }
   });
   ```

   Add the reference to JavaScript file generated by WebPack in Layout:

   ```
   <script src="~/js/dist/build.js"></script>
   ```
7. Run the Watch - Development task under WebPack in Task Runner Explorer to watch for changes and build the final JavaScript file. Run the solution in Visual Studio (Ctrl+F5 or F5).

[image]